# A question Kolmogrov's generalized inequality for projection onto convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

Kolmogrov's inequality says that, if $C$ is a convex set, and $P_C(x)$ is an operator for projecting point $x$ into the convex set $C$, if $z = P_C(x)$, then for any $y \in C$ we have
$$
(z - y).(x - y) \leq 0
$$

My question is about a results in [1] (Page 17, Proof of Proposition 11): 
It is saying that, given a strongly convex function $R(\mathbf{w})$ and a projection onto convex set $\mathcal{K}$,

$$  
\mathbf{w}_{t+1} = \Pi_{\phi_t, \mathcal{K}}( \bar{\mathbf{w}}_{t+1} ),  
$$
defined as:
$$
\Pi_{\phi_t, \mathcal{K}}( \bar{\mathbf{w}}_{t+1} ) \triangleq \arg\min_{ \mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{K} }D_{\phi_t} ( \mathbf{w}, \tilde{\mathbf{w}}_{t+1}). 
$$
It says that this holds (Page 17, Proof of Proposition 11):
$$
\langle \nabla R(\mathbf{w}_t) - \nabla R(\mathbf{w}_{t+1} ), \mathbf{w}_{t} - \mathbf{w}_{t+1} \rangle \leq \langle \nabla R( \tilde {\mathbf{w}}_t) - \nabla R(\tilde { \mathbf{w}}_{t+1} ), \mathbf{w}_{t} - \mathbf{w}_{t+1} \rangle
$$

Question: why the above inequality holds?

[1] http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~rakhlin/courses/stat991/papers/lecture_notes.pdf

Answer (score 4):

To answer this, you must write down the optimality condition,

given an optimization problem as:

$\mathbf{x^*}= \operatorname{argmin}_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{K}}  f(\mathbf{x}) $

The optimality condition asserts that for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{K}$

$\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^*)^\top(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x^*}) \ge 0 $

Writing this condition for the optimal point $\mathbf{w}_{t+1}$ and $\mathbf{w}_{t}$, noting that $\nabla f(\mathbf{w}_{t+1})=\nabla \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{w}_{t+1})-\nabla \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{\hat{w}}_{t+1})$ you get to the inequality that you mentioned.